# Javafx Tile Pane, set max number of columns

Tags: user-interface, javafx

First of all, i will explain my objetive. I want render a table like this:

[image]

The content of every cell is determined in Execution Time, but his size is fixed to 13x13.

So, my approach is create a tile pane, set the numbers of columns to 13 and create the cells.

```
pane = new TilePane();
pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
pane.setVgap(5);
pane.setHgap(5);
pane.setPrefColumns(13);
```

This works:

[image]

But when i resize the window:

[image]

There are more of 13 columns now!

My test code:

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            TilePane pane = new TilePane();
            pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
            pane.setVgap(5);
            pane.setHgap(5);
            pane.setPrefColumns(13);
            pane.setMaxWidth(Region.USE_PREF_SIZE);
            ObservableList<Node> list = pane.getChildren();

            for (int i = 0;i < 200;i++){
                Label view = new Label();
                view.setText(""+(i+1));
                list.add(view);
            }

            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane,400,400));
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Setting the max width to use the preferred width is the correct approach. The only problem with the code in your example is that you have made the tile pane the root of the scene. The root node will always be sized to the size of the scene, *ignoring the minimum, maximum, and preferred size*. (If you don't specify a size for the scene, then the scene is sized according to the preferred size of the root node, but the root node is still allowed to grow or shrink arbitrarily.)

So if you simply wrap the tile pane in another pane, it will work as expected:

```
primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(pane)));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice point, but there is another problem now... It isn't reponsible, the width of the cells don't change when you resize the window.

Comment: @amchacon Perhaps you could edit your question to include all your requirements? The [`TilePane` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/TilePane.html) says 'The size of each "tile" defaults to the size needed to encompass the largest preferred width and height of the tilepane's children... The application may also control the size of the tiles directly by setting `prefTileWidth`/`prefTileHeight` properties...' So the only way to do this would be by binding the `prefTileWidth` and doing some computation. It would probably be easier to use a `GridPane`.