# How can I Lock TilePane Buttons

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to create a small phone GUI using javaFx.

It has been recommended to me by my professor to use tilePane.

I currently have 12 buttons successfully displaying, however, unlike a phone, they are not locked in a 3x4 grid.

How the buttons should be no matter the size of the window:

[image]

But how they appear...

[image]

How would I stop this?

```
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    // Create a Button or any control item
    Button Button1 = new Button("1");
    Button Button2 = new Button("ABC\n  2");
    Button Button3 = new Button("DEF\n  3");
    Button Button4 = new Button("GHI\n  4");
    Button Button5 = new Button("JKL\n  5");
    Button Button6 = new Button("MNO\n  6");
    Button Button7 = new Button("PQRS\n  7");
    Button Button8 = new Button("TUV\n  8");
    Button Button9 = new Button("WXYZ\n  9");
    Button ButtonStar = new Button("*");
    Button Button0 = new Button("0");
    Button ButtonPlus = new Button("+");

    // Create a new grid pane
    TilePane pane = new TilePane();

    pane.setPrefColumns(3);
    pane.setPrefRows(4);

    pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
    pane.setMinSize(300, 300);
    pane.setVgap(10);
    pane.setHgap(10);

    //set an action on the button using method reference
    Button1.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button2.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button3.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button4.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button5.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button6.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button7.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button8.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button9.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    ButtonStar.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    Button0.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);
    ButtonPlus.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);

    // Add the button and label into the pane

    pane.getChildren().add(Button1);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button2);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button3);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button4);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button5);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button6);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button7);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button8);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button9);
    pane.getChildren().add(ButtonStar);
    pane.getChildren().add(Button0);
    pane.getChildren().add(ButtonPlus);

    // JavaFX must have a Scene (window content) inside a Stage (window)
    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,100);
    stage.setTitle("Phone");
    stage.setScene(scene);

    scene.getStylesheets().add("ButtonLook.css");

    // Show the Stage (window)
    stage.show();      
}
```

Comment: whatever you teacher tells you, make it a habit to read the api doc as well :) setting both prefRows and prefCols will not do what you (probably) expect it to do. Note, that the tilePane is _not_ a fixed grid of nodes but a grid of equally sized nodes which are layed out either horizontally or vertically inside the available width/height. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: a general hint when layouts are not what you expect (besides comparing your expectation with the api doc .. repeating to jam it in :) - remove all manual sizing (min/max/pref and actual) interference and see what happens. More concretely: you interfer with the layout at two lines ...

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43370303/3992939)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javafx Tile Pane, set max number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43369963/javafx-tile-pane-set-max-number-of-columns)

Comment: When you want to create a **grid** of nodes, why would your teacher tell you to use anything other than a `GridPane`, which is meant for that exact purpose?

Comment: @Zephyr he/she may want to guarantee all tiles are of the same size.